# How to realod bootstrap table after post via ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap table to display a rows from a database, it's MVC ASP.NET and I've put my data in a ViewBag and returned that View with viewbag included as a data to display, so it looks like this:

```
<div class="row rpad">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="z-panel-2">
                <div class="oneRow">
                    <table id="cT">

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Date & time
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Type
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Homework done
                                </th>

                                <th>
                                    Teacher
                                </th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.AllClasses)
                            {
                                <tr class="class" id="@item.ID">


                                    <td>@item.Date</td>
                                    <td>@item.Type.Name - @item.User_Class.ClassType.NumberOfLessons</td>
                                    <td>
                                        @if (item.HomeWorkDone ?? false)
                                        {
                                            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        }
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.User.Name
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
```

As it's possible to notice I'm looping all data `ViewBag.AllClasses` and I'm displaying a data as a rows in a table..

When users clicks on a row I'm updating a database with values : homework is readen : true

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("setHomework", "homework")',
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: id },
```

And next time user reloads a page, this condition will be executed (as mentioned in a code above):

```
@if (item.HomeWorkDone ?? false)
 {
       i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 }
```

Code above means if user has value of true on a homework field, fontawesome icon will be displayed so he will know that he red that homework, but I'm wondering how can I realod content of this bootstrap table after he clicked on that row, so he do not need to reload page to see that mark (font awesome icon) on that row.. ( as a sign that homework is red)

I hope there is another way instead of refreshing whole page/view..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a success callback to your ajax call. Inside that.. you could append a td to that row.

```
   $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("setHomework", "homework")',
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {
                if (data == "1") { // worked as it should

  $(row).find('td:last').after('<td><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>');

     }
    }
  });
```

I think a cleaner way will be to have a `td` there by default and just change the class of icon depending on `item.HomeWorkDone`. So it would be something like:

```
  $(row).find('.fa-exclamation-circle').addClass('fa-check').removeClass('fa-exclamation-circle');
```

Also, it is recommended to use HTTP POST for update operations.